# Added content in editable email notification still not reflecting any change in emails in BXP Jenkins

Tags: email, jenkins, notifications

Jenkins version: 1.606

In editable email notification configuration section,
Added:

```
$BUILD_NUMBER

$CAUSE

$FAILED_TESTS
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note all variables used in editable email notification should be like `${VAR}` format.For example:

```
${PROJECT_URL}
${JOB_DESCRIPTION}
${GIT_BRANCH}
${CHANGES}
${PROJECT_URL}
${CAUSE}
${BUILD_URL}
```

And below is an example:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for it. I am trying to get my html console output of a script to Jenkins email. Tried changing default type to HTML , doesn't seem to help. Can you suggest anything on that?